# Fairy tale generation by GA

Tags: python, algorithm, genetic-algorithm

Some of you may already read [this](http://www.technologyreview.com/view/537716/machine-learning-algorithm-mines-rap-lyrics-then-writes-its-own/) - Machine-Learning Algorithm Mines Rap Lyrics, Then Writes Its Own article. This gave me a inspiration to generate a fairy tale because it's mostly written for children(could be simple and interesting). I think this generation process can be seen optimization problem.

[Genetic algorithm](http://www.ai-junkie.com/ga/intro/gat1.html) seems a great way to solve optimization problem. There are lot of resources(project gutenberg, grim's fairy tale collection etc) on the internet and can be used as a input for the algorithm(population(collection of fairy tales) & individuals(each of fairy tale) and it's elements(sentences, plots, characters, events etc)). And output would be a fairy tale that can at least make sense.(doesn't matter whether it's boring or not)

So I'm wondering if there is any way to create a program in python? is there any python library for this?

And also I'm not sure on the evolution(mutation,crossover,breeding) part. How it could be done?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, that rap lyrics generator does not seem very impressive to me, it just selects lines from different songs and shuffles them such that they rhyme. The article even says that the resulting poem doesn't make any sense. I don't know why they even had to use machine learning for it...

In my opinion, there is much more impressive similar work out there, in particular [this approach for generating Shakespearean sonnets](http://www.npr.org/2014/02/10/274785962/wherefore-art-thou-robo-shakespeare-or-better-yet-how). It's more impressive because the algorithm only acts as a **coauthor**, which lets a human make decisions as well. Basically, the algorithm learnt what kind of words Shakespeare used and in which contexts and then it was used to suggest new words for something that a human started. Kind of like your smartphone's keyboard suggesting new words.

For both kind of problems, I think genetic algorithms are the wrong way to go. They are slow and while they can be used as learning algorithms, you will get better results with specialized algorithms. For the second approach (where the algorithm acts as a coauthor) you want something that can suggest words (could be anything from Naive Bayes to Neural Networks and SVMs). For the first approach (where the algorithm completely generates the work), you can try the approach presented by the authors of the rap song generator, although seeing their result I don't really see why a simple dictionary of words that rhyme couldn't also do the trick.

As far as I know, fairy tales don't have a simple structure like rap songs, so I believe you'd have more success with something that helps you coauthor fairy tales. If you try to have an algorithm generate them on its own, the result will not be very good at all.